# Is there a constant $C$ such that $z=x^2+y^2+C$ is tangent to $x^2+y^2=z^2$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Per the title, does a constant $C$ exist such that the surface of the paraboloid $z=x^2+y^2+C$ is tangent to the surface of the cone $x^2+y^2=z^2$? How would I find this constant?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Since the cone has constant slope, the paraboloid has all slopes in $[0,\infty)$ and you can use $C$ to make them match, the answer to the first question is yes. To answer the second question, it would make things easier to replace $x^2+y^2$ by $r^2$, since they don't appear separately.

Comment: Thanks! That's a useful tip. I'm getting $C=1/4$ for the constant such that the paraboloid is tangnet to the cone, is this accurate?

Comment: @ro44 Yes, I believe $1/4$  is the answer.

Comment: @Jon: Thanks. Also, you shouldn't have deleted your answer, I think, I didn't read it entirely yet but different approaches are always good, right?

Comment: @ro44 No problem, and my answer is essentially the same as what joriki suggested you to do, since those two surfaces are rotational-invariant with respect to the $z$-axis, meaning if you try to look at them from any perspective perpendicular to the $z$-axis, you can't tell the difference, hence draw a cross-section viewing from $y$-axis of both surfaces, so that you could visualize it as to find $C$ such that at somewhere $z = x^2 + C$ is tangent to $z = \pm x$, the rest is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. $C=1/4$. You can see this by following up on @Joriki's suggestion and solving the equivalent two dimensional problem:
$$y=r^2+C=|r|$$
$$y'=2|r|=1$$